# mongodb on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic systemctl handling of mongod.service / mongodb.service

Tags: mongodb

I had some issues installing `mongod.service` on a digital ocean droplet with `systemctl`. It is set up now except that it complains there is something else taking its port, although nothing actually is. The culprit, I suppose is the following: there is a failed service for `mongodb` (rather than `mongod.service`) whose error is "file not found". Do I need to set up or remove the missing `mongodb.service`? I see there is a `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` but there's not a `mongodb.service` in that directory.

Here is some of the config in `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

I also set `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db` which fixed errors then but now I'm getting `/data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied`

...Yay mongod is running after `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle`
I suppose that file was generated and missed getting the permissions.

I just read in the documentation: `The Linux package init scripts do not expect storage.dbPath to change from the defaults. If you use the Linux packages and change storage.dbPath, you will have to use your own init scripts and disable the built-in scripts.` I believe I had originally changed the dbPath...

Comment: Post what are the errors are you seeing? its always better to check that your MongoDB is running or not by the command `ps -Aef | grep mongod`

Comment: That returns ```dev      24561 23345  0 04:35 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongod```

Comment: This means that your mongod is not running on your localhost, start mongo db after providing the proper permission to /data/db folder and logs `sudo service mongod start`. For details check the official documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#start-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

check if mongodb is running

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

if it says inactive, activate using the below command

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the detail steps to check the MongoDB running on the localhost or not and how to start it.

1. To check MongoDB running or not type below command on Linux terminal

   `ps -Aef | grep mongod`

After this command, you will properly see the details of mongod running instance with details of process Id and config file loaded by MongoDB.

[image: Start and status of MongoDB command]

2. **If not running** then check the status as below

   sudo service mongod status
3. Provide the permission to /data/db or change the location and provide the monogdb ownership of that folder as `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db` Once done then do restart the MongoDB as below

   `sudo service mongod start`
4. Now check again the status, its working or not. Still facing issue then visit the official MongoDB documentation with proper install guideline [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition-on-ubuntu)